# Are these for loop the same?

Tags: python

I have a big file and need to loop in lines where the file contains three columns
I know this a simple question but my experience is still a beginner with python and searched to make sure that those lines same
Does these lines
`for i in xx:`  will be the same result with `for i in range (N):`
where `N = len(xx)` and `xx = pd.read_csv(the file)`

as I need to do this calculation in for loop

```
 ii = xx[0][i]-1
 jj = xx[1][i]-1
```

Comment: `for i in N` will give you a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: ohh excuse me i mean range(N)

Answer (score 0):

They are different

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120]})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['c1'], row['c2'])
```

This will give you what you want

If you run

```
for i in df:
  print(i)
```

It will give you only the columns in the dataframe not the rows

As for

```
for i in N:
```

It wont work as you are not providing a range

but if you do

```
for i in range(N):
    df['c1'][i]
```

It will give you the index of rows only and not the rows of your dataframe, but you can use i to get rows by using **df['c1']**

Try printing each to see the difference.

For large data set you will need chunk

use

```
chunksize = 100000   #number of rows in each chunk
with pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
            print(row['c1'], row['c2'])
```

now each chunk will act as a new dataframe with only 10000 rows.

change the chunk size as per your need

Comment: i need to make usage of memory is  less. so can this loop `for index, row in df.iterrows():` do it?

Comment: pandas will store the df in memory only. so it dose not matter if you use loop. if data is huge you will have to use chunks

Comment: thanks can you give me an example please , this in not for loop only but this loop take a lot of memory and make other code killed

Comment: remember at the end you will need to append your data frames to a single output file.

Comment: thanks for the helping I will try now .. but if I need to use the results I can read from the file right ? i mean without problem ? and excuse me if i have 160 million lines I need to make the size of chunk 160 000 000 ?

Comment: chunk size is the size of one chunk.. so you can try 400000 or more.. chunking is basicaly reading data part by part

Answer (score 0):

No, `N = len(xx)` is the length of the `xx`. You have to include it into `range(N)` to iterate over the numbers 0-range(N). If you loop over `xx` you directly loop or iterate over the panda you created from the csv file.

Comment: excuse me  if the times of len(xx) equla 10 times and I loop in xx directly does the result of iterative times will be 10 also ?

Comment: Both will iterate 10 times in your example. But the results will differ

Comment: thanks but how can i loop in the file without using memory ?